# How to choose every column couple and iterate through through the code pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Small part of data frame is:

```
border = 

12_longitude_1  12_latitude_1   14_longitude_2  14_latitude_2   15_longitude_3  15_latitude_3
            11             12               13             14               15            16
            11             12               13             14               15            16
            11             12               13             14               15            16
```

I want to do this, but getting `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` error in `curr_lat_name = border.columns[col_num + 1]`:

```
pd_out = pd.DataFrame({'zone': [], 'number': []})

for col_num in range(0, len(border.columns), 2):
    curr_lon_name = border.columns[col_num]
    curr_lat_name = border.columns[col_num + 1]
    num = curr_lon_name.split("_")[-1]
    border = border[[curr_lon_name, curr_lat_name]].dropna()
    border[curr_lon_name] = border[curr_lon_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    border[curr_lat_name] = border[curr_lat_name].replace(r'[()]', '', regex=True)
    border[curr_lon_name] = pd.to_numeric(border[curr_lon_name], errors='coerce')
    border[curr_lat_name] = pd.to_numeric(border[curr_lat_name], errors='coerce')
    geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(border[curr_lon_name],border[curr_lat_name])]
    border_point = gpd.GeoDataFrame(border,crs=crs,geometry=geometry2)
    turin_final = Polygon([[p.x, p.y] for p in border_point.geometry])
    within_turin = turin_point[turin_point.geometry.within(turin_final)]
    curr_len = len(within_turin)
    pd_out = pd_out.append({'zone': "long_lat_{}".format(num), 'number': curr_len}, ignore_index=True)
```

Desired output:
[image]

Libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what the code is actually doing? I’m having some trouble following, and i’m not familiar at all with `shapely`. Why are you using a DataFrame? Manipulating column names like this doesn’t seem ideal.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile It will be too long to explain. But my question is related to `curr_lon_name` and `curr_lat_name` . I was doing `border = border[['12_longitude_1','12_latitude_1']].dropna()` before. But I have 338 couples. I dont want to do it 1 by 1. I need loop

Comment: So is `border` a DataFrame throughout the whole program?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes it is

Comment: Alright, i’ll give it a shot. Be back soon :)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile btw, there is another data frame as well. which is `turin`. Maybe we can start a `chat` and I will share with you some sample data?

Comment: @user11901353 Had I responded to your request to chat? I could have sworn I had, but it looks like I never commented here again.